# Easy Way to Invoke PhotoSwipe On Images List

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

From the document of PhotoSwipe I got the below snippet.

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>
```

The document at http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html does not explain how to easily invoke the PhotoSwipe on the images. It does give some long code to do but I am not happy to use that as its too complex.

The document says if I use jQuery, the code can be made simpler.

> If you use frameworks like jQuery or MooTools, or if you don't need to
>   support IE8, code can be simplified dramatically.

But I am not able to find it in the docs or in search. So how should I invoke PhotoSwipe based on this?

Comment: Would like to know too - surprised no one's written a jquery plugin to couple photoswipe to your own markup.

Answer (score -2):

I found this on github

https://gist.github.com/di5abled/d8d84af3be5e1bf12507

hope this helps

- edit -

I followed this tutorial successfully, sorry for the first link

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-lightbox-using-photoswipe-with-jquery--cms-23587

Comment: Can you explain more about your answer?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.